# Drupal 6 - Core Search Module Not Indexing Node Titles

Tags: 6, search

Search is working fine on my site if the search includes text that is in the body of a node, but it appears that node titles are not being indexed.

I'm just using the core search module.

Is this by design in Drupal 6 or is this a bug and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by changing the **Indexing throttle** setting for `Number of items to index per cron run` from 100 down to 10.

Once reindexing was complete all node titles appear to be indexed and appearing in search.